# How TabNavigator Implement in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to implement tab navigator in react native.The link from which i get the code is
     https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab
The Problem is that when i run the code i get the error 500 type i also at the end attach the picture of the error.Plz resolve the issue if any one know about it the code is....

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    // Note: By default the icon is only shown on iOS. Search the showIcon option below.
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
        style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
      />
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    );
  }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Notifications',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./notif-icon.png')}
        style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
      />
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        title="Go back home"
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 26,
    height: 26,
  },
});

const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('TabNavigator', () => MyApp);
```

when i run this code i get the error

[image]
Even i use the simple stack navigator on that time i also get the same error
the code of stack navigator i get from this link

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/

Comment: Is this `source={require('./chats-icon.png')}` your line or is it just the example code?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that a local image can not be found. 
There are  two options:

1. Create a `chats-icon.png` and a `notif-icon.png` and place them both in the directory where the file you copied the content from is at.
2. Replace `source={require('./chats-icon.png')}` and `source={require('./chats-icon.png')}` with `source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}` to use an example remote image.

This should eliminate the 500 error and let you continue working.

Comment: Well, then check out: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/923

Comment: i chk this they say install the latest version i install the latest version but not work..If you have an other code for stack navigator and tab navigator then plz tell..May it helpful for me...Thans sis for response....:p